# Copying only rows with Data, pasting them transposed into another sheet in column C onwards

Tags: vba, copy, range, paste, transpose

I have tried various methods of selecting the rows from which I want to copy and paste to columns as the data is transposed. I keep getting intermittent run error 1004, sometimes it works but mostly doesn't, basically not reliable. I am hoping someone can tell me a reliable efficient way to complete this action.

To explain what I am trying to do. I have a workbook with a sheet of data arranged in rows ( can vary  in number of rows).So I have specified last row as lrow. I am trying to copy this data transpose and paste into a different workbook and sheet, I need to ensure that the data is not pasted in either row A or B, it can be in any following column.

```html
Dim lRows As Long
Dim lCols As Long
Dim wsData_Sheet As Worksheet 

lRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lCols = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column
wsData_Sheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lRows, lCols)).Copy

Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Matlab\R2006b\work\INCALogCommentList v01\LatestMacroSheet.xlsm")


With y.Sheets("Sheet1")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate

Cells(2, 3).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End With
```

I keep getting either a range object defined error on the data being copied, for no reason I can think of or paste error.